# Data Compression list of dictionaries that all have the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, key

My task is:

Assume you have a list of dictionaries that all have the same keys. For example:

```
** [
     {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
     {"a": 9, "c": 7, "b": 8}, # dictionary keys don't have any order
    ...
 ]**
```

Write a function compress that takes such a list of dictionaries as a parameter data. The function should perform two tasks, best illustrated by the result below. First, it should extract all keys, sort them alphabetically (as the Python sorted function does it), and store them in a tuple. Second, it should create a tuple for each dictionary, where the values of the dictionary are stored in the correct order.

Finally, the function should return a tuple that itself contains the keys as a tuple and a list containing the value tuples.

When called on the previous example, your function should return the following data:

```
**(
    ("a", "b", "c"),   # keys in a tuple
    [
        (1, 2, 3),     # values of each dictionary
        (9, 8, 7)      # values in correct order corresponding to the keys!
    ]
)**
```

You can assume that the provided parameter is always a valid list of dictionaries and that all these dictionaries in the list share the same keys. However, the order of the keys might be different among the dictionaries.

Make sure that your solution also works for empty lists or for empty dictionaries. The return value should always be a tuple with two values. If data is an entirely empty list, the result tuple should contain an empty tuple and an empty list. If data is a list containing an empty dictionary, then the result tuple should contain an empty tuple as the first value and a list containing an empty tuple as the second value.

```
# This signature is required for the automated grading to work. 
# Do not rename the function or change its list of parameters.
def compress(data):
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
              
            if data[j][0] > data[j + 1][0]:
                data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]
    return data
    

# The following line calls the function and prints the return
# value to the Console. This way you can check what it does.
# However, we encourage you to write tests, because then you
# can easily test many different values on every "Test & Run"!
data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}
]
print(compress(data))
```

I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "403ccdf4-1a54-443a-8a7d-63c88c92823b.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(compress(data))
  File "403ccdf4-1a54-443a-8a7d-63c88c92823b.py", line 8, in compress
    if data[j][0] > data[j + 1][0]:
KeyError: 0
```

Sorry if its a dumb question, i'm realy know at python and i dont even know if my code works

Comment: Key error means that the key does not exist in that dictionary, like when one has keys a, b, and c, and the other has a, c, and d. Then accessing the 2nd with key c will cause that error. You can use the `setdefault` function, or check with `if key in dict:` or wrap the dict access in a  `try` ... `except` and ignore the key error.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a homework question, so it's likely better for you to think about how to solve the problem than someone on stack overflow giving you a direct answer. However, a few hints that may help you:

1. Your `compress` function is far too complex, you don't need to use `len` and `range` to solve this problem efficiently
2. Since your dictionaries are stored in a list, you can iterate over them (something like `for dict_ in data:`)
3. You can access the keys of a dictionary using the `.keys()` method (something like `dict_.keys()`
4. If you require to sort the keys like `sorted` does, then it's likely useful to include `sorted` somewhere in your solution

Hope these help!